# Universal App Campaign define keywords to show ads

Tags: android, ads

I know its not good question to ask here in stackoverflow but also I have seen people asking [questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680968/google-adwords-how-does-target-cpi-affect-performance-android-app) So, My question is:

I have created a app called "Wish Later" and used Universal App Campaign with $2 budget. App has a SMS Collection, Event Manager and Sms Scheduler and I want to ad when people search for sms collection, event manager, sms scheduler or text later, And I have configured **Ads text idea** as
SMS Collection
Text Later
Event Manager
SMS Scheduler

because I have not seen Keyword to define. However my app appears only when I search "Wish Later". I am getting only about 7 impression  and 0 clicks per day. :( **How can I appear my ads when people search for those keywords??** Any help would be appreciated.

I have also tried **Display Search Network Campaign** and also made it $2 budget but got 15K impressions and 141 clicks but no downloads :( So, I decide to use Universal App Campaign for those keywords.

Answer (score 0):

UAC (universal app campaign) uses "Text ideas" and Play Store / App Store title (probably Play Store short description too!) for Search Network. If you want to show your ads by your keywords in Search Network with UAC, you must use keywords in UAC campaign "Text ideas" and app store titles.
But in any case, UAC campaign will choose the best (cheapest) option for your product between Display Network and Search Network.

*Mostly Display Network is cheaper than Search Network in terms of CPI